# Помогите подружить .pack() с виджетами canvas (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Я делаю имитацию окна входа пользователя, где ему нужно ввести имя и пароль.
Скрипт писал используя canvas (чтобы загрузить картинку на фон) - соответственно использовал виджеты canvas вместо label и pack(). Всё шло хорошо, пока не потребовалось сделать переход на новое окно с помощью frame и frame.pack.forget (когда пользователь вводит верные данные, его перенаправляет на новое окно - старое забывается).

**ПРОБЛЕМА:** как писал выше, на форуме мне предоставили решение с переходом через frame.pack.forget, но проблема заключается в том, что canvas не дружит с pack() и виджеты просто не отображаются (я перенёс строчки кода в мой скрипт с canvas - не работает).

**Мой изначальный код (без перехода):**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
dict_pass = {
    'Роман'    : '111',
}   

#window
root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("1020x780")

root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\xampp\\anonymous\\python.png")


#canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=323, height=576, bd=0, 
highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

my_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=bg, anchor="nw")

text_id = my_canvas.create_text(350, 500, text='', font='Verdana 30')


def Doctype():
   my_canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text='Вход выполнен', fill='Green')

def Error():
    my_canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text='Ошибка авторизации!', 
fill='Red')

def GetText():
    name=name_entry.get()
    password=pass_entry.get()
    for key, value in dict_pass.items():
        if name == key:
            if password == value:
                return Doctype()
    return Error()


#objects
my_canvas.create_text(370,200, text='Пользователь', fill='Yellow', 
font='Verdana 22')
my_canvas.create_text(420,300, text='Пароль', fill='Yellow', 
font='Verdana 22')


name_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', 
bg='White')
pass_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', 
bg='White')


name_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 190, anchor="nw", 
window=name_entry)
pass_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 290, anchor="nw",
window=pass_entry)


btn = Button(root, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, 
bg='White', fg='Black', command=GetText)
btn_window = my_canvas.create_window(420,370, anchor='nw', window=btn)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: Спойлер 1]
[image: Спойлер 2]

**Предложенный мне ответ с переходом без Canvas (без фона):**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

dict_pass = {
    'Миша': '415'
}


def log_in():
    try:
        if dict_pass[name_entry.get()] == pass_entry.get():
            frame.pack_forget()
            frame_log_inned.pack()

    except KeyError:
        pass


root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("640x480")

root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

frame = Frame(root)

Label(frame, text='Пользователь').pack()

name_entry = Entry(frame, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, 
fg='Black', bg='White')
name_entry.pack()

Label(frame, text='Пароль').pack()

pass_entry = Entry(frame, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, 
fg='Black', bg='White')
pass_entry.pack()

btn = Button(frame, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, 
bg='White', fg='Black', command=log_in)
btn.pack(pady=10)

frame.pack()

frame_log_inned = Frame(root)

Label(frame_log_inned, text='Успех').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Спойлер 3]
[image: Спойлер 4]

Прошу помочь как-то сделать переход на новую страницу с моим изначальным скриптом в canvas. Так как хочется сделать с фоном. Буду очень благодарен, если найдёте решение!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал, держи!

Кратко что поменял:

1. Изменил функцию `Doctype()` на `show_logged_in_screen()` для показа нового окна при успешной авторизации. Так название более говорящее. Запрос был открывать новое окно — теперь открывается новое окно.
2. Добавил возможность скрывать окно авторизации и показывать новое окно успешной авторизации с помощью метода `withdraw()` и `Toplevel()`.
3. Изменил функцию `Error()` на `show_error_message()` для вывода сообщения об ошибке на холсте. Опять же, более говорящее имя, и из него понятно, что не создаются окна, а просто показывается сообщение.
4. Функция `GetText()` была заменена на `do_login()`, которая осуществляет обработку введенных данных и выводит соответствующее сообщение или новое окно. Мы же получаем не просто текст, а данные с формы авторизации.
5. Добавил глобальную переменную `bg` для хранения фонового изображения и её переиспользования в функциии. Т.к. теперь есть новое окно, соблюдаем DRY и используем дважды, подгрузив картинку лишь один раз.
6. Пароль теперь под звёздочками. Так безопаснее! ‍♂️
7. После ввода логина и пароля можно просто нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd> не жмакая по кнопке и не наводя туда курсор.
8. Установил цвет фона `#242424` для окна и фреймов, чтобы заполнить области вокруг изображения при растягивании окна, чтобы не было белых полос.

В остальном комментарии по коду даны.

```python
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

dict_pass = {
    'StackOverflow': 'по-русски',
}

bg = None  # Переменная для хранения фонового изображения
bg_color = '#242424'


def show_error_message():
    my_canvas.create_text(300, 470, text='Ошибка авторизации!', fill='Red', font='Verdana 30')


def show_logged_in_screen(main_canvas):
    root.withdraw()  # Скрываем окно root
    success_window = Toplevel(root)  # Создаем новое окно
    success_window.title('Успешный успех!')
    success_window.geometry("1020x780")

    # Вывести фоновое изображение на холсте нового окна, используя уже загруженное изображение
    success_canvas = Canvas(success_window, width=323, height=576, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    success_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    success_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor="nw")

    # Установить цвет фона холста
    success_canvas.configure(bg=bg_color)

    success_canvas.create_text(370, 300, text='Успех!', fill='Green', font='Verdana 30')

    success_window.mainloop()


def do_login():
    name = name_entry.get()
    password = pass_entry.get()
    for key, value in dict_pass.items():
        if name == key and password == value:
            frame.pack_forget()  # Скрыть окно авторизации
            show_logged_in_screen(my_canvas)  # Показать новое окно успешной авторизации
            return

    # Если вход не выполнен, вывести сообщение об ошибке на холсте ниже формы авторизации
    show_error_message()


def on_enter_pressed(event):
    # Обработчик события нажатия клавиши "Enter" на поле ввода пароля
    do_login()


root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("1020x780")
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

# Установить цвет фона окна root
root.configure(bg='#242424')

# Создать объект ImageTk.PhotoImage и привязываем его к глобальной переменной bg
# Будет использоваться на обоих экранах
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="../../Prog/python.png")

# Создать холст (canvas) в окне авторизации
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=323, height=576, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor="nw")

# Установить цвет фона холста
my_canvas.configure(bg=bg_color)

frame = Frame(root)

# Элементы на экране авторизации
my_canvas.create_text(370, 200, text='Пользователь', fill='Yellow', font='Verdana 22')
my_canvas.create_text(420, 300, text='Пароль', fill='Yellow', font='Verdana 22')
name_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
pass_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White',
                   show='*')  # Пароль отображается под звёздочками
btn = Button(root, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, bg='White', fg='Black', command=do_login)

# Добавить поля для ввода и кнопку на холст
my_canvas.create_window(500, 190, anchor="nw", window=name_entry)
my_canvas.create_window(500, 290, anchor="nw", window=pass_entry)
my_canvas.create_window(420, 370, anchor='nw', window=btn)

frame.pack()

# Назначить обработчик события нажатия клавиши "Enter" на поле ввода пароля
pass_entry.bind("<Return>", on_enter_pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

Не забудь поменять путь к изображению на свой. Кстати полезно было бы в вопросе предоставить [изображение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHp1o.png), чтобы его не перерисовывать…

По итогу у меня так работает:

[image: Окно авторизации и неправильный пароль]

[image: После успешной авторизации]

По хорошему тут бы ещё не использовать фоновое изображение, а использовать логотип с прозрачностью и ставить его в нижний правый угол. Сплошной фон можно и так средствами TK сделать. А ещё лучше в векторе отрисовать.

Comment: Очень интересно. Спасибо, что с душой отнеслись. Жаль, не получилось всё-таки на том же окне сделать.. Никак нельзя, да?

Comment: Ну почему же, можно. Это даже проще. Стираете весь канвас и записываете новый. Я по вопросу понял, что нужно именно новое окно. К тому же с новым окном можно старое оставить при необходимости.